# Python, looping with defined function, but output strange values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I define a function as below, `EmiCtry`, `percapita`, and `year` are global parameters.  I would like to see the effect of choosing different `shreshold` and `ramprate`.

```
def annual_emi_scale(shreshold, ramprate):
    tmp = EmiCtry
    for i in range(177):
        for j in range(91):
            if percapita[i,j] >= shreshold and year[j] >= 2020:
                tmp[i,j] = tmp[i,j] * (1.-ramprate)
    adj1 = cdutil.averager(tmp, axis=0,weights='equal',action='sum')
    adj2 = cdutil.averager(adj1,axis=0,weights='equal',action='sum')
    return adj1, adj2
```

Then I do a loop with the defined function:

```
emi  = np.zeros([25, 91]) 
cum  = np.zeros([5,5])
for ii in range(5):
    shre = (ii + 1) * 20
    for jj in range(5):
        ramp = jj * 0.02
        emi[ii*5+jj],cum[ii,jj] =  annual_emi_scale(shre, ramp)
```

The outputs are strange for `ii` > 0 and it seems after each loop `tmp = EmiCtry` does not work at all.  That is, for `ii = 3`, `tmp = EmiCtry` will use the value of tmp when `ii = 2`.

However, when I do `tmp1, tmp2 =  annual_emi_scale(80, 0.00)` before the loop, the results are correct. But when I put it after the loop, the same thing happen again.

`EmiCtry` is calculated from other data and is an `numpy.array()` with float type values: `co2EmiCtry = original_data.astype(np.float)`

Comment: "Does not work at all" is not a very useful statement of the problem.

Comment: Could you please describe what this code is supposed to do, and why the results are "strange"?

Comment: Do you mean the `i` that is used inside `annual_emi_scale` or the `i` from the main loop?

Comment: It sounds like `EmiCtry` is a mutable type and you are modifying the original. `tmp = EmiCtry` is not necessarily copying the exisiting data into a new container. It may just get `tmp` to point to the same container. Could you please clarify what type is `EmiCtry`?

Comment: `EmiCtry` is calculated from other data and is an `numpy.array()` with `float` type values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the array `EmiCtry` to prevent the modifications on `tmp` to affect the original.

Your line `tmp = EmiCtry` just binds the name `tmp` to the same object that `EmiCtry` is pointing to. Both names points to the same location in memory. If you modify one, the other will be modified too.

To make an independant copy of the array, use `tmp = numpy.copy(EmiCtry)`

Comment: Great!  This does work!         I start to remember that in python `=` is creating a link between two variables but not making an copy...   Thanks!